# Page Title In Silverlight 4

Tags: silverlight, silverlight-4.0

I'm newbie to silverlight. Please help me find setting page title.
[image]

See I don't want /Pages/Page1.xaml in browser title.

```
private void hlHome_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        //HtmlDocument document = HtmlPage.Document; 
        //document.SetProperty("title", "Sample Title");  
        this.frameContainer.Navigate(new Uri("/Pages/Home.xaml", UriKind.Relative));
    }

    private void frameContainer_NavigationFailed(object sender, System.Windows.Navigation.NavigationFailedEventArgs e)
    {
        e.Handled = true;
        frameContainer.Navigate(new Uri("/Pages/ErrorPage.xaml", UriKind.Relative));
    }
```

Comment: What does the full URL look like in the Address bar?

Comment: @AnthonyWjones: http://localhost:4816/SilverlightApplication1TestPage.aspx#/Pages/Page1.xaml

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It sounds to me that you haven't specified the `Title` property in your `Page1.xaml`.

```
 <navigation:Page x:Class="NavApp.Views.Page1" 
       xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation" 
       xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml" 
       xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
       xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
       mc:Ignorable="d"
       xmlns:navigation="clr-namespace:System.Windows.Controls;assembly=System.Windows.Controls.Navigation"
       d:DesignWidth="640" d:DesignHeight="480" Background="Blue"
       Title="Your title here"
       >
```

Altenatively if you need to assign the title dynamically you can do it in code during `OnNavigatedTo` in the code-behind.

Answer (score 2):

Try This:

```
HtmlDocument document = HtmlPage.Document;
document.SetProperty("Title", "Sample Title");
```

Reference [Here](http://forums.silverlight.net/t/51933.aspx)

Comment: Where this code should be written? I tried this but didn't work.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. Will this code should be written in xaml file or .aspx file?

Comment: @Mohan This needs to be in your Silverlight navigation code. When you make the new view visible call this.

Comment: @ChrisF: Can you please send me complete code? Not getting it.

Comment: @Mohan - this is the complete code. Just insert this in your Silverlight code when it gets displayed. You haven't given enough detail about your application to say exactly where it should go.

Comment: This mucking about with the Title property via the HTML bridge is unnecessary in a navigation app and probably won't work on some browsers.

Comment: I think that "Title" should not work. Instead of "Title" use "title". This might solve lot of headache.

Answer (score -1):

HtmlPage.Document.SetProperty("Title","Sample");

Worked for me